# Website ftp details hacked by Alsancak Tim

Tags: hacking

My web files are hacked by Alsancak Tim.

some ine is hacked ftp username and password.
then going to delete all files and updated his own file.

Now i am looking my website, it display a new index.html file (added by hacker). but mysql database is safe.

i am all changing ftp details and re uploading all my files. now it is good.

what can i do for protecting my website ?

Comment: Restrict ftp access on a per-ip basis